# Error while Connecting postgres using Hibernate. - NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Am getting below exception while connecting to postgresql,

```
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.sri.hibernate.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDataBase</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>
       <property name="format_sql">true</property>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
       <mapping class="org.sri.hibernate.beans.UserDetails"/>
     </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

My connection URL, user Name and password are correct. Am trying to connect by using,

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session ss=sf.openSession();
        Transaction tran=null;

        UserDetails det= new UserDetails();
        det.setDateOfBirth(new Date());
        det.setUserName("SomeName");

        try
        {
            tran=ss.beginTransaction();
            ss.save(det);
            tran.commit();
            ss.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }
```

I use the same code to connect Oracle DB ( after changing the properties in xml ) it works fine, am I missing something specific to postgres ? Please help

Comment: can u post stack trace

Comment: Ooops, I had missed main part :), added

Comment: Not sure this is the only problem, but your URL is not right: `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDataBase`. It has a leading double quote that shouldn't be there.

Comment: That is it, Sorry Guys, I should not have even posted this here.. Thanks @JBNizet